# Individual Phase plot looks different than the Bode plot

Tags: circuit-design, bode-plot

My transfer function is [image]

with Omega_n = 1000.8 and Lambda = .5004 and k = 3

But when I try to individually plot the phase I get something like this[image]

I believe my equation for finding the Phase using ArcTan function is right. Does anyone know why my individual phase plot does not look like phase plot in BodePlot?

Comment: For starters the x axis in the upper plots is logarithmic.  Try using a log axis on your plot and see if it becomes identical.

Comment: You should use something like atan2 which is inverse tangent but not restricted to -90 to 90 degrees as the one you used. ;)

Comment: Don't know which language you are using, but in some there is a arctan2, which unwinds the angles, so that they are not constraint between -90 and 90 degree.

Comment: I am trying to do it in excel. But this is mathematica. Any idea how I can do it in excel

Comment: As the others have said, `atan2()` is the four quadrant version of `atan()`. What you're seeing is the *wrapping*, that is, if the phase will vary more than `+/-90deg` the output will "reset the counter". As can be seen in the phase graph, your min/max are `+/-90deg` (`+/-pi/2`). `atan2()` will wrap it around `+/-180deg`. For more, you'll need to *unwrap* the phase. For your simple experiment, I'd suggest using LTspice with a `Laplace` expression, in an `.AC` analysis.

Comment: I have done that. But i need to make a spreadsheet for the transfer function in excel.

Comment: What is that? Mathematicia? Yuk

Comment: In Mathematica one should use ArcTan[x,y] instead of ArcTan[x/y] to avoid these jumps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about maths primarily and how to use the correct tan function in excel.

Answer (score -1):

Take care in arctg(A/B) when B < 0 (add 180 degrees in result).
In your case, when x > 1000.8. 
When x = 1000.8, occurs a division by 0.